# Axios Request Error - Message serialization failure (Invalid encoding)

Tags: node.js, firebase, axios, google-cloud-functions

I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: 13 INTERNAL: Request message serialization failure: invalid encoding
```

When I try run this `axios` post. Any ideas what's wrong? (I've tried a number of different versions but the error isn't so specific)

Running this on Node.js using Axios from a Firebase Function.

```
 const result = await axios.post('https://example_api_url.com', {
            data1: "data1",
            data2: "data2,
        }, {
          headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${API_KEY}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }});
```

Comment: You have a typo, should rather be "data2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error seems to come from the **node.js grpc** client [library](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/blob/master/packages/grpc-js/src/client-interceptors.ts#L353).

gRPC is a language-neutral, platform-neutral, open source, remote procedure call (RPC) system initially developed at Google. gRPC-enabled Cloud APIs generally have both REST and RPC interfaces, so rather than just using JSON over HTTP to talk to the REST interface, gRPC-enabled API clients can also use protocol buffers and gRPC over HTTP2 to talk to the RPC interface. You can explore more details about it in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/client-libraries-explained#grpc_apis).

The **error should not come from the use of axios library**, as it has nothing to do with grpc. This makes me think that the error might be coming from the **service itself**, rather than the client, but it's hard to be sure.

Since it is a grpc client error it's quite likely that a Google API is being called with some kind of invalid data.

Again, the **responseEncoding** is not related, since the error message mentions the **request**, not the **response**. Furthermore, the example is confusing, since it contains two values for the same responseEncoding key.

Comment: This was correct in the end. I worked out that the response from axios was returning correctly but I was not passing that response on correctly from the firebase function service and hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the encoding and responseType to the request:

```
 const result = await axios.post('https://example_api_url.com', {
            data1: "data1",
            data2: "data2,
        }, {
          headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${API_KEY}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'responseEncoding' : 'json',  // the type of data server will respond
            'responseEncoding': 'utf-8' // used only for node.js
          }});
```

I am attaching the [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios?activeTab=readme#request-config) documentation, I recommend go through its configuration object property details.

Comment: I still get the same error with those headers added. (also when changing json to responseType header)